# How do you properly dispatch an action in vuex? Getting error [vuex] unknown action type in Chrome

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to add some data to a restful endpoint with vuex, and Chrome keeps throwing the following error: vuex.esm.js?2f62:438 [vuex] unknown action type: POST_REGISTER - Any help / insight you can provide would be extremely helpful.

Here's what I have setup.

**In a vuex module:**

```
import actions from './actions.js'
export default {
actions: {}
}
```

**In actions.js:**

```
import client from '@/services/authService.js'

export const POST_REGISTER = 'POST_REGISTER'

export default {
    [POST_REGISTER]: (context, data) => client.post('auth/register', data)

}
```

**in authService.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api/v1/'
})
```

**My call from the vue component:**

```
import {POST_REGISTER} from "@/store/auth/actions"
methods: {
  createOrUpdate: function(login) {
    this.login.username = login.username
    this.login.password = login.password
    this.$store.dispatch(POST_REGISTER, this.login)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never actually use the `actions` import in the vuex module. Try the following:

```
import actions from './actions.js'
export default {
actions
}
```